# How to implement AirPush banner ads?

Tags: android, ads, airpush

Can anyone help me to implement AirPush banner ads ?
I am trying to do this according to their documentation.But i think that there documentation is not good enough.
Because i am copying the same code they have given.And still i am not able to receive any banner ads.
Though i can receive notification & smart-wall ads but not banner.
Please help me.
Here is their documentation.
http://manage.airpush.com/docs/index.php?title=Android_SDK_6.0_Documentation

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: Don't use airpush - They are a scam - they never pay (to me and to 2 of my friends) or pay much less due to all sorts of reasons they make up.. (google it)